# Java job gives OOM error inconsistently

Tags: java, linux, hadoop, memory

I have scheduled(cron) a jar file on Linux box. The jar connects with Hive server over JDBC and runs select query, after that I write the selected data in csv file. The daily data volume is around 150 Million records and the csv file is approx. of size 30GB.

Now, this job does not completes every time it is invoked and results in writing part of data. I checked the PID for error with `dmesg | grep -E 31866` and I can see:

```
[1208443.268977] Out of memory: Kill process 31866 (java) score 178 or sacrifice child
[1208443.270552] Killed process 31866 (java) total-vm:25522888kB, anon-rss:11498464kB, file-rss:104kB, shmem-rss:0kB
```

I am invoking my jar with memory options like :
`java -Xms5g -Xmx20g -XX:+UseG1GC  -cp jarFile`

I want to know what exact the error text means and Is there any solution I can apply to ensure my job will not run OOM. The wired thing is the job does not fail every time its behaviour is inconsistence.

Answer (score 1):

That message is actually from linux kernel, not your job. It means that your system ran out of memory and the kernel has killed your job to resolve the problem (otherwise you'd probably get a kernel panic).

You could try modifying your app to lower memory requirements (e.g. load your data incrementally or write a distributed job that would complete needed transformations on the cluster, not just one machine).